# Como 'leer' los errores HTTP que dan como respuesta las apis?

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, guzzle

Estoy consumiendo varias api's, necesito validar la respuesta que me dan para yo mostrar las respuestas, si obtengo una respuesta valida puedo leer el statusCode:

$http_status= $response->getStatusCode();

el problema es que si de parte del servidor hay otra respuesta no me deja leer el código, me redirecciona directamente el error, pero como comento tengo mas apis consumiendo, si estas responden 'ok' necesito mostrar esas respuestas.

me pueden ayudar? estoy ocupando guzzle

---

mil disculpas, me explico más a detalle:
ocupo las api's para cotizar, yo muestro todas las respuestas en una sola vista, una api no es muy estable, cuando llega a no estar disponible me manda el siguiente error:

cURL error 28:Failed to connect to api.pagina.com : Time out

que es un error 500, entonces es aquí donde necesito saber el código de la respuesta, si es una respuesta diferente a 200, omito la consulta y sigo con mis demás consultas. Como decía la función **getStatusCode()** no llega a ejecutarse sino que en automático se muestra el error de arriba, espero haberme explicado mejor

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con: “otra respuesta”? ¿Por qué dices que no te deja “leer el código”?  ¿Quién te “redirecciona” y a dónde?

Comment: Aquí nos falta informacion. Si esas API cumplen los estándares (rest, soap, etc) no debes tener problemas. Pero hay empresas que no cumplen esos estándares. Tendríamos que tener la documentación de cada una de ellas para revisar casos...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tendrias que agregar tu codigo.. un error 500 es devuelto por la red, no por la api, y por eso te salta antes.